# Business Investment Loss from prior year

Tags: investing, business, losses

In 2011, I invested $30,000 into a restaurant. I was a passive investor. I wrote a personal check from my account to the business entity.

A year later, the restaurant closed and all my money was lost.

Can I deduct that loss somehow in the 2015 tax year? Or is it too late?

Comment: Please include your country.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give specific dates! In the United States, you have three years to file an amended tax return.

> https://www.irs.gov/uac/Newsroom/Ten-Facts-about-Amended-Tax-Returns

Did the restaurant fail in 2012? If so, that's probably the year to take the loss. If you need to amend your 2012 return, which you filed in 2013, you should have until 2016 to file this. The exact date may be based on when you filed 2012 taxes!